# ASP.NET MVC 2 edit controller doesn't work using viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

Hey, the problem is that edit controller in ASP.NET MVC 2 doesn't work. I tried many ways and nothing works.

Here's a sample code:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit() {
    var edit = new UserViewModel {
        User = Database.Users.Single(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
    };

    return View(edit);
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection formCollection) {
    var edit = new UserViewModel {
        User = Database.Users.Single(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
    };

    // TODO: try, catch
    UpdateModel(edit, "User");
    Database.SaveChanges();

    return View(edit);
}
```

Here's a view model class:

```
public class UserViewModel {
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

What should I do to update this user model to database? A the moment I'm using only Email field:

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
<div>
    <div class="UserFieldLeft"><%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Email) %></div>
    <div class="UserFieldRight"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.Email, new { style="width: 200px" }) %></div>
    <div class="UserFieldHelper"><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Email) %></div>
    <p><input class="UserFieldInput" type="submit" value="Zmień email" /></p>
</div>
<% } %>
```

If I work on native user model it doesn't work too. What's wrong? Where did I made a mistake?

By the way, I've to use view model to add (in future) some checkboxes (hair color, length, etc.) to my user.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the prefix "User".

```
UpdateModel(edit);
```

should work. In the formsCollection their should be a key with User.Email. This should map to the Email property in the User Object.

Comment: I did it and saw an error "The model of type 'Project.ViewModels.UserViewModel' could not be updated. I really don't understand what's wrong. I've read a few tutorials and this method worked good.

Comment: I think the problem is with your User object. What kind of object is it? You can try UpdateModel(edit.User, "User", new string[] { "Email" }); To only update the Email property of the User.

Comment: I think you're right.I've just created a new MVC2 application without any providers or validatiors. Worked good. User object is taken from SQL Server 2008. It's compilation user fields with default membership class.

Comment: The problem was in partial user class - user_validation. Now it updates a model but doesn't validate data. I'm confused.

Comment: I would recommend asking a new question on stackoverflow with the specifics of the user and user_validation